# web2py: How to execute further code after ajax call

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, web2py

I have two dropdown/select widgets on a form. I am trying to set the options of the second select through an ajax call in jQuery, and then execute further code. The ajax call is successful and correctly sets the second select options, but it seems the code after the ajax call is not executed at all. How to correct this?

view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}`
<h1>{{=title}} /This is the library/edit_user.html template</h1>
{{=grid}}

<script>
    jQuery("#no_table_region_id").change(function(){
        region_id = $(this).val();
        branch_id = jQuery('#no_table_branch_id').val();
        ajax("{{=URL('library', 'branches')}}" + '?region_id=' + region_id, [], 'no_table_branch_id');
        jQuery('#no_table_branch_id').val(branch_id); # this does not execute
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // todo: solve the unsettable branch_id
        jQuery("#no_table_region_id").change();
    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
def branches():
    if request.vars.region_id:
        branches = db(db.branch.region_id==request.vars.region_id).select(db.branch.ALL)
        ops1 = ['<option value=""></option>']
        ops = ops1 + [f"<option value={i['id']}>{i['branch_name']}</option>" for i in branches]
    else:
        ops = ''
    return ops
```

Comment: It looks like when the region_id is updated, you are trying to (a) store the currently selected branch_id (presumably associated with the previously selected region_id), (b) get a new list of branch_ids, and then (c) restore the previously selected branch_id. Do you generally expect the previously selected branch_id to be available in the new set of options?

Comment: @Anthony, I am positive that the previously selected branch_id is available in the new set of options. I do this because as soon as the `branch_id` is set to the new options, the first choice is selected, which is the 'zero' option. What I want is for it to retain its previous value.

Comment: Btw Anthony, how do my posts get recognized in the web2py international google group? I already registered as member for a while now, but my posts seems to need some admin intervention approval of some kind before appearing in the group message.

Comment: I don't see any pending messages at https://groups.google.com/g/web2py. There is also a Brazil group, but it doesn't appear to be active.

Comment: @Anthony, that's strange. I posted twice in the past. Now I posted once more this same question to test. I hope it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line after the `ajax` call *is* executed. However, because the `ajax` function makes an asynchronous call, its results are not returned and used to update the DOM until *after* that next line has already run.

Note, the third argument to `ajax` can be a callback function that takes the result of the Ajax call, so you can use that method to update the options and *then* set the value:

```
ajax(
    "{{=URL('library', 'branches')}}" + '?region_id=' + region_id,
    [],
    options => {
        jQuery('#no_table_branch_id').html(options);
        jQuery('#no_table_branch_id').val(branch_id);
    }
);
```

Comment: TIL: Arrow functions are a thing.